# nextUntil() is not working in this case

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
  <tr class="codesgroupheader"><td>Header1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="codesgroupheader"><td>Header2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class="codesgroupheader"><td>Header3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr class="codesgroupheader"><td>Header4</td></tr>
</table>
```

And here is the jQuery code

```
$('.codesgroupheader').not(':last').each(function() {
   alert($(this).nextUntil('.codesgroupheader').find('tr').size());
});
```

But It always returns me zero..

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What's it supposed to alert?

Comment: @rocket I am trying to access all the TR elements between two classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does the following:

```
$(this)                        // <tr>           <-- = this
.nextUntil('.codesgroupheader')// All elements between this and <tr class="...">
.find('tr')                    // Seeks for a <tr> inside <tr> - Not found
```

If you want to select the number of `<tr>` elements with the given class, use:

```
alert($('tr.codesgroupheader').not(':last').length);
```

If you want to get the number of `<tr>`s between the current and next `<tr class=...>`, use:

```
// this = any <tr>
$(this).nextUntil(".codesgroupheader", "tr").length;
```

For additional reference and usage of the `nextUntil` function, see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

Comment: Thank you so much.. You always rocks.. I like your way of coding style.. Till now you have answered many of my questions and every answer is accepted :-).

Comment: I think you've misunderstood `nextUntil('.codesgroupheader')`.  Per the [jQuery doc for nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), that will get all the siblings up until (and not included) the next one that matches `.codesgroupheader`.  So, in this case, it will get the intervening tr row that isn't `.codesgroupheader`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess that Sol wanted to match the `<tr>` elements *between* the current, and next `.codesgroupheader` element. If you want to include `colgroupheader`, use the [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) method.

Comment: I thought your first explanation of what his code does was wrong or at least very misleading and certainly not helping him understand what nextUntil does.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your comments :-) This worked for me.. Actually my requirement was to itearate through all the elements between two .codesgroupheaders. But TR elements are parents between the classes. So I have taken TR to get all. And first explanation is correct. The below answer also stating the same :-)

Comment: My point is that this line of your explanation is wrong `.nextUntil('.codesgroupheader') // <tr class="codesgroupheader">`.  That does not select `<tr class="codesgroupheader">`.  It selects the siblings up to, but not including that object.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see, that explanation was indeed somewhat ambiguous. I've edited the answer (also deleted some comments which are not relevant to the answer to keep the page clean).

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the current `tr` element.

`nextUntil('.codesgroupheader')` will find all elements between `this` and the next `tr.codesgroupheader`.

Your `.find` tries to search inside that set (so inside the `tr`). you can skip the `find` completely, or if for some reason you believe there can be other elements in there, use `filter` instead (*or the second parameter to [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil)*), which filters the current set.

So either use

```
$('.codesgroupheader').not(':last').each(function() {
   alert($(this).nextUntil('.codesgroupheader').size());
});
```

or to filter

```
$('.codesgroupheader').not(':last').each(function() {
   alert($(this).nextUntil('.codesgroupheader').filter('tr').size());
});
```

or (*using second parameter of `nextUntil`*)

```
$('.codesgroupheader').not(':last').each(function() {
   alert($(this).nextUntil('.codesgroupheader', 'tr').size());
});
```